# How to compare two JSON responses in java irrespective of JSON array sequence?

Tags: java, json, algorithm

As per business need I have to compare JSON response of API URL , which suppose to be a generic solution.
JSON compare needs to be include value mismatch as well as schema mismatch too.

As per the requirement is to be a generic solution.
I can not create a java object as per the response and compare as response JSON can be anything with any schema ,so  JSON to object convention is not possible as object structure can not be defined before hand and will change with each sets of API.

**What I tried** :
Try to implement

Approach 1)  flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch: This is an implementation of RFC 6902 JSON Patch written in Java (github.com)

Approach 2) https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener

**But with this implementation problem is that**

**but Main issue is that** , all is doing case to case matching and able to handle mismatch in  sequence in response.
Suppose API response of two API as follows for which I want to compare….

Response of API 1

```
{
"name": "name1",
"address": "",
"skillset": [
  {
    "lang": "java",
    "projectName": "project1"
  },
  {
    "lang": "c++",
    "projectName": "project2"
  }

]
}
```

Response of API 2 :

```
{
"name": "name1",
"address": "",
"skillset": [
  
  {
    "lang": "c++",
    "projectName": "project2"
  },
  {
    "lang": "java",
    "projectName": "project1"
  }

]
}
```

In this two JSON response , array element are same but they not matching index wise in skillset array.
My requirement is like this as for name "name1", as skillset is same (just the response order is different), I have to consider this as  "no mismatch" in JSON response.

But the above two implementation showing it as mismatch in JSON response and in skill set array , sequence is different in both the response.

May be this can be easily done by json to java object conversion and then do the object compare. But as this is a generic solution and JSON response schema is not known beforehand so its not possible to create any object structure.

Any one can suggest any approach , tool or process through which this can be achieve? Mainly I need to do a json comparation irrespective of JSON array sequence.

Comment: Note that arrays with different data for the same indices are definitely not equal. If this is your API that you're pulling from,, you really want to sort the data as part of the json response instead.

Comment: yes , Mike , that's true , I am not saying implementation of approach 1 and 2 is/are wrong.  they are perfectly ok , but as per my requirement I have to check the value containment also in those response , on the basis of that need to decide data are matching or not. Logically  for "name1" as per API response there is no mismatch. I have judge on the basis of value.

Comment: Right but is this your own API's data? If so, this needs a sort at the API server point. If not, sorting the `skillset` before comparing would also get you there (without jumping through lots of hoops) but would be much more fragile. How are you turning your JSON into objects? (that information seems to be missing from your post, so please remember to include that, as it can change what a useful answer looks like)

Comment: yes Mike , those are our APIs. yes Sorting can be a option, but sorting in which order ? for sorting also object conversion will be needed and my problem this is not a single API based solution where I know the schema / object structure before hand. Purpose of this tool is to compare any 2 given API response with there meaning not just string based line by line comparation.

Comment: "in which order" doesn't actually matter, what matters is that all array content is guaranteed to use the same ordering every time. Usually you do a default sort on record id (with different sorting applied only if the API request has explicit sorting instructions) or whatever the compound primary key is for derived records.

Comment: The problem with assuming differently ordered arrays are "the same" is that his is patently false for a ton of data. For example, these two arrays are almost certainly _not_ the same: `"inputOrder": [4, 8, 11]`, `"inputOrder": [11, 4, 8]`, so now you still need to know which fields are safe to treat as equal  and which are not. Which is why your API should always respond with the same data ordering for the same data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/octomix/josson
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.octomix.josson/josson

This new library can do the job.

```
implementation 'com.octomix.josson:josson:1.3.20'

------------------------------------------------

ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode api1 = mapper.readTree("{\n" +
        "\"name\": \"name12\",\n" +
        "\"address\": \"\",\n" +
        "\"skillset\": [\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"lang\": \"java\",\n" +
        "    \"projectName\": \"project1\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"lang\": \"c++\",\n" +
        "    \"projectName\": \"project2\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]\n" +
        "}");
JsonNode api2 = mapper.readTree("{\n" +
        "\"name\": \"name12\",\n" +
        "\"address\": \"\",\n" +
        "\"skillset\": [\n" +
        "  \n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"lang\": \"c++\",\n" +
        "    \"projectName\": \"project2\"\n" +
        "  },\n" +
        "  {\n" +
        "    \"lang\": \"java\",\n" +
        "    \"projectName\": \"project1\"\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "]\n" +
        "}");
System.out.println(api1.equals(api2)); // -> false
Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("api1", Josson.create(api1));
jossons.putDataset("api2", Josson.create(api2));
System.out.println(jossons.evaluateQuery("api1 = api2")); // -> true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something similar to your requirement
Not 100% sure but maybe this could help

You need your mapper to read the tree
Assuming you are using Jackson

You can have

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode object1=mapper.readTree(response1):
JsonNode object2=mapper.readTree(response2);


assertEquals(object1, object2);
```

Even though the order is not the same, it should give you true.

Click [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) for more